# Trying to get my program to read an input file correctly 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, input, multidimensional-array, ifstream

I am trying to make my program read my input file correctly, the following is my input file, the first column is what I want the user to input and then the values need to be taken out from the corresponding row, the values being read are wrong though.

14, 14,  8, 0.4, 16,  2.0, 1.7, 7, 4.7, 0.23, 0.44, 290, 350

16, 16, 10, 0.5, 17,  2.2, 1.8, 8, 5.4, 0.27, 0.5, 310, 370

18, 18, 11, 0.5, 18,  2.2, 2.0, 9, 6.0, 0.30, 0.56, 320, 380

20, 20, 12, 0.5, 19,  2.3, 2.2, 9.5, 6.4, 0.32, 0.59, 330, 390

22, 22, 13, 0.5, 20,  2.4, 2.4, 10, 6.7, 0.33, 0.63, 340, 410

24, 24, 14, 0.5, 21,  2.5, 2.5, 11, 7.4, 0.37, 0.69, 350, 420

27, 27, 16, 0.6, 22,  2.6, 2.8, 11.5, 7.7, 0.38, 0.72, 370, 450

30, 30, 18, 0.6, 23,  2.7, 3.0, 12, 8.0, 0.40, 0.75, 380, 460

35, 35, 21, 0.6, 25,  2.8, 3.4, 13, 8.7, 0.43, 0.81, 400, 480

40, 40, 24, 0.6, 26,  2.9, 3.8, 14, 9.4, 0.47, 0.88, 420, 500

45, 45, 27, 0.6, 27,  3.1, 3.8, 15, 10.0, 0.50, 0.94, 440, 520

50, 50, 30, 0.6, 29,  3.2, 3.8, 16, 10.7, 0.53, 1.00, 460, 550

```
    ifstream soft;
    soft.open ("Softwood.txt"); //Opens the softwood text file which holds the values required for calculations 

cout <<"Please enter the strength class of the timber, excluding the letter." <<endl; 
cin >> type;

float a [12][13]; //begins the array so the input file can be read

int i, j;

for (i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<13; j++)
        soft>>a[i][j];
}


int m=0;

while(a[m][0]!= type && m<12)
 {
m++;
 }
bendingStrength = a[m][1];
tensionParallel = a[m][2];
tensionPerpindicular = a[m][3];
compressionParallel = a[m][4];
compressionPerpindicular = a[m][5];
shearStrength = a[m][6];
elasticityParallel = a[m][7];
elasticityParallelFive = a[m][8];
elasticityPerpindicular = a[m][9];
shearModulus = a[m][10];
density = a[m][11];
meanDensity = a[m][12];
```

Comment: Just think about where it goes wrong, and print some debug statements, for starters.

Comment: I've noticed this is the 3rd question along these lines you've posted in the last 2-3 days. Maybe you need to rethink how your program is working. It should be possible to come up with a more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ignore comma while reading the file. It could be acomplished like this:

```
for (i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<13; j++)
    {
       soft >> a[i][j];
       char ch;
       soft.get(ch);
       if(ch != ',')
           soft.unget();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have put this in but it isnt recognising ch in 'cin.get(ch);'?

Comment: @user3077409 sorry, my fault:( I've edited my post try now

Comment: I have just tried this and it still seems to be reading the values incorrectly, I will go through it a bit more, thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3077409, try again I've corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
while(a[m][0]!= type && m<12)
 { 
m++;
 }
```

If m == 11, your program increments the value of m (now m == 12) and you try to assign the value of a[12][i] (for i between 1 and 12) to an object. But in arrays in C++, we count the number of object from 0 so the biggest number in your array is a[11][12]. Your programm tries to read the value of an object which doesn't exist.